# Having a readline() use the strings saved to a variable in its prompt - R

Tags: r, string, variables, command-prompt, readline

I'd like a readline() function to use the strings stored to a variable rather than convert the word used for the variable into the string. Is there a way I can do this?

For example, say I have the following variables and desired prompt:

```
> SpringC = c("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green")
> WinterC = c("Blue", "White", "Purple", "Grey")
> x <- readline("Enter Season Color: ")
```

From this I'd like it if this would happen is:

```
Enter Season Color: WinterC
> x <- as.character(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))

> x
"Blue" "White" "Purple" "Grey"
```

Rather than what actually happens:

```
Enter Season Color: WinterC
> x <- as.character(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))

> x
"WinterC"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is something you can do with a user defined function. Something like this:

```
#define the function
readline_2 <- function() {

  x <- readline("Enter Season Color: ")
  eval(parse(text = x))

}
```

Use:

```
> b <- readline_2()
Enter Season Color: WinterC
> b
[1] "Blue"   "White"  "Purple" "Grey"
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are very welcome, happy to help :). For simple problems like the one you describe `eval(parse...` will work fine, but for more complicated ones I think MrFlicks idea is better because it does not rely on text parsing (which is what `eval(parse...` is).

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier if you stored your related values in a list rather than separate varaibles

```
options <- list(
    SpringC = c("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green"), 
    WinterC = c("Blue", "White", "Purple", "Grey")
)
x <- readline("Enter Season Color: ")
x <- options[[x]]
```

Otherwise you can use `get()` with the string value of the name of a variable to retrieve it but I strongly recommend the former solution.

Comment: When I try this method it still doesn't come out with the colors, it comes out with "options[[1]]" or "x <- options[[1]]"

Comment: This works if it's sourced as one block
else you need to put your reply after the readline lines like

`x <- readline("Enter Season Color: ")
WinterC
options <- list(
    SpringC = c("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green"), 
    WinterC = c("Blue", "White", "Purple", "Grey")
)
as.character(options[[x]])`